# How to get the price history of forex in TDAmeritrade API such as EUR/USD?

Tags: api, forex

I use the TD Ameritrade API as documented on the [API documentation](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/price-history/apis/get/marketdata/%7Bsymbol%7D/pricehistory).

The URL to get the price history contains the symbol of the asset to fetch.

[image]

The documentation says:

> Replace the `{symbol}` in the URL with the actual symbol

It works well with stock symbols like GOOG or AAPL or FB.

For example for AAPL, the url would be: https://api.tdameritrade.com/vi/marketdata/AAPL/pricehistory

But with symbols that contain a backslash like the `EUR/USD` spot, it does not work because the backslash is considered as an additional path to the URL
So I get URL not found with https://api.tdameritrade.com/vi/marketdata/EUR/USD/pricehistory

Same with `EUR/CAD`, `EUR/GBP`, and other forex spots.
How to fetch forex spot?

Comment: See URI encoding. Assuming the symbol is valid, / would be encoded as %2F for ../EUR%2FCAD/.. eg.

Comment: I assume that no price history for forex with TD api

Answer (score 2):

Use a dot instead of the slash between the currencies. So this will work:
https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/EUR.USD/pricehistory

Yeah, the docs are rubbish about it and even the symbol lookup returns the slash as part of the symbol eg. GBP/USD as a valid symbol:

```
{
  "GBP/USD": {
    "symbol": "GBP/USD",
    "description": "GBPound/US Dollar Spot",
    "exchange": "GFT",
    "assetType": "FOREX"
  }
}
```

Comment: This works well for Forex where the slash is in the middle of the symbol, but it doesn't work for futures where the slash is at the beginning; e.g. /CLZ21   Neither .CLZ21 nor %2FCLZ21 seems to work.  Any ideas on this one?

Comment: This was working great for Forex, but it appears to have stopped working.  Did TD change the format of Forex symbols, or are they not letting us retrieve Forex historical data now?

Answer (score 2):

Only **Stocks**, **Options** and **Index prices** are available from the `pricehistory` endpoint. I received an email from one of TD Ameritrades product managers confirming as much:

> Hello Tobiah,
>
> Thank you for the email and I apologize for the delay in response.
>
> **Forex data is only available via the Get Quote endpoint**.  Here is an
> example of a request for multiple forex symbols at once for an in the
> moment snapshot quote:
> https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/quotes?apikey=YING4&symbol=EUR%2FUSD%2CUSD%2FJPY
>
> **Get Price History is only available for stocks, options, and Index**
> currently.  Futures and Forex instruments would not be available
> through that endpoint.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Michael Ying Product Manager,
> Trader TD Ameritrade 600 W Chicago Ave,
> Chicago, IL 60654

Answer (score -1):

for other broker (X Trade Brokers) you can request EURUSD price history in NodeJS
https://github.com/peterszombati/xapi-node#get-eurusd-m1-price-history

request price history with this module is simple like this code

```
x.onReady(() => {
    x.getPriceHistory({
        symbol:'EURUSD',
        period: PERIOD_FIELD.PERIOD_M1
    }).then(({candles, digits}) => {
        console.log(candles.length);
        console.log(candles[0]);
        console.log('digits = ' + digits);
    })
});
```

Comment: more details would be appreciated by the question author.